# Custom message on devise lockable n-th attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm looking for a method to display custom messages for a various numbers of failed attempts in devise lockable module.

I found out that only the last attempt could be notified by default:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L121

Is there any elegant way to display different warning message for say 7th, and 8th failed attempt? Could you propose one?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is interesting but won't work because `lockable` is called before `create`, so I created a custom action which I call before `create`.

This worked for me:

```
class User::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :check_failed_attempts, only: :create

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    # some code
  end

  def create
    super
    # create some stuff and check others
  end

  def destroy
    # may be destroy and deal with cookies
    super
  end

  def check_failed_attempts
    flash.clear

    email = self.params["user"]["email"]
    return unless email

    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return unless user

    failed_attempts = user.failed_attempts
    maximum_attempts = User.maximum_attempts
    attempts_left = maximum_attempts - failed_attempts - 1
    if attempts_left != maximum_attempts and attempts_left > 1
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.failure.n_attempt', attempts_left: attempts_left
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the Devise code with

```
module Devise::Models::Lockable
  def unauthenticated_message
    # If set to paranoid mode, do not show the locked message because it
    # leaks the existence of an account.
    if Devise.paranoid
      super
    elsif access_locked? || (lock_strategy_enabled?(:failed_attempts) && attempts_exceeded?)
      :locked
    elsif lock_strategy_enabled?(:failed_attempts) && last_attempt? && self.class.last_attempt_warning
      :last_attempt
    else
      return "invalid_fail_attempt_#{failed_attempts}" if temporary
      #super normally this would return :invalid see super class
    end
  end
end
```

then you would need to add your translations for

```
devise.failure.user.invalid_1: "one shot down! 4 to go"
devise.failure.user.invalid_2: "ooh 2 strikes!!"
devise.failure.user.invalid_3: "3 strikes!! but your not out yet! 2 left"
```

and you don't need number 4 as that would be handled by the block that runs on `last_attempt?` (assuming you have a 5 attempt limit, adjust as needed.)

That code might also go in the super class wherever that is..

Answer (score 0):

maybe a custom SessionsController, I'm guessing that devise uses dynamic methods, I couldn't find where :last_attempt was called to just override the unauthenticated_message method

```
def create
    if self.resource.failed_attempts != self.resource.class.maximum_attempts - 1 and self.resource.failed_attempts != 0
        attempts_left = self.resource.failed_attempts
        flash[:alert] = I18n.t 'some_path.errors.attempts', attempts_left: attempts_left
    super
end
```

The idea is to add a flash alert when you have 1 or less than the max attempts, in the max attempt case and the last attempt case you would get the default messages