# Devise: lockable - last_attempt_warning not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, devise

I'm trying to implement the `:lockable` module to my devise following [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:lockable-to-Users) but ran into some issues. In development, when login attempted more than `maximum_attempts` times, the `failed_attempts` attribute gets updated correctly and the user account gets locked but:

1) despite `config.last_attempt_warning = true` no warning message is displayed

2) I get an `unlock_instructions` email, but when I copy paste the link into the browser, I get an `invalid authorisation token` error.

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# ==> Configuration for :lockable
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
config.unlock_keys = [:email]
config.unlock_strategy = :email
config.maximum_attempts = 3
config.last_attempt_warning = true
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
end
```

**views/devise/sessions/new**

```
= flash[:alert] if flash[:alert]
= flash[:notice] if flash[:notice]

= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true
    = f.input :password, required: false, autocomplete: "off"
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Log in"
```

**db/migrate/YYYYMMDDxxx_add_lockable_to_devise.rb**

```
class AddLockableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :users, :failed_attempts, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_column :users, :unlock_token, :string
    add_column :users, :locked_at, :datetime
    add_index :users, :unlock_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

I don't have any migrations pending, also tried resetting the db and restarting the server but with no luck.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the form in your `views/devise/sessions/new` template? That page should surely contain more than just a couple of `flash` messages!

Comment: As for your second question, what is causing the error? Are you perhaps requiring users to already be logged in when unlocking the account (which wouldn't make sense)? Have you verified that the unlock token gets saved correctly in the database?

Comment: @TomLord yeah, the form is obviously there, I just didn't think it was relevant so I didn't paste it but can add it now. As for the second question I didn't do any setup of my own so I don't think I'm requiring them to be logged in. I can also see the token in the db but it's not the same token as in the email so I'm not sure how to verify if they're correct.

Comment: If the token in the db and email are different, then it's _not_ correct! Please clarify exactly what you mean by that. What are you looking at in the database and email?

Comment: @TomLord I really appreciate you taking your time to look into my problem but perhaps you could cut down on the exclamation marks a little ;-) What I mean is the following: `User.first.unlock_token `=> "95923c615feeb3781dc2584e339a89bc4c4e9b4710924727f976dcf618f2a707"` and my mailer generates the token as follows: `link_to 'Unlock my account', unlock_url(@resource, unlock_token: @token) => http://localhost:3000/users/unlock?unlock_token=3D6ne-CyRyzgnuHuFSZ2iB`. I was reading about tokens not being stored literally in the db for security reasons, that's what I meant by them not being the same.

Comment: @TomLord Since I figured out what the second issue was about, it clarifies the tokens questions: while my `unlock_token` in the db was 'http://localhost:3000/users/unlock?unlock_token=3DqjycRsszb=
tKZjXDGsB4' and the `unlock_token` in the link was 'qjycRsszbtKZjXDGsB4P' I was able to successfully unlock the acount through the link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After lots of digging, I managed to solve both issues:

#### Warning message not displaying

The first issue was caused by the config:

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.paranoid = true
```

If you have a look at the [devise module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L121):

> If set to paranoid mode, do not show the locked message because it
>   leaks the existence of an account.

Depending on your security requirements, you can either change this value to `false` or keep the emails secret and not provide feedback.
If you're interested in customising your message on failed log in attempts I strongly recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004275/custom-message-on-devise-lockable-n-th-attempt).

---

#### Invalid authorisation token

The second issue was caused by me copying the link directly from the source code of the email - since `=` is encoded as `3D=`, the link was obviously breaking. Further explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895282/escaping-of-rails-generated-url).

*Hope this helps someone if they run into similar issues.*

Comment: The best answer found in 8 hours of searching. Ty!